# Select count between dates & All time counts in one query Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I want to select count of impression between the dates and All time impression as well, can we do this in one query ?

This is my query in which I am able to get impression only in between dates

```
SELECT
    robotAds."Ad_ID",
    count(robotScraper."adIDAdID") as ad_impression
FROM
    robot__ads robotAds
LEFT JOIN robot__session__scraper__data robotScraper 
    ON robotScraper."adIDAdID" = robotAds."Ad_ID"
LEFT JOIN robot__session_data robotSession 
    ON robotSession."id" = robotScraper."sessionIDId"
    AND robotSession."Session_start" BETWEEN '2020-11-25 00:00:00'
    AND '2021-04-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY
    robotAds."Ad_ID"
```

What I have to do to get count of all time impression in this same query.

Thanks

Comment: please always provide a [mre] and take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can :

```
SELECT
    robotAds."Ad_ID",
    count(robotScraper."adIDAdID") filter (where robotSession."Session_start" BETWEEN '2020-11-25 00:00:00'AND '2021-04-01 00:00:00') as ad_impression,
    count(robotScraper."adIDAdID") count_alltime
FROM
    robot__ads robotAds
LEFT JOIN robot__session__scraper__data robotScraper 
    ON robotScraper."adIDAdID" = robotAds."Ad_ID"
LEFT JOIN robot__session_data robotSession 
    ON robotSession."id" = robotScraper."sessionIDId"
     
GROUP BY
    robotAds."Ad_ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

"Conditional aggregation" should meet this need. Essentially this is using a case expression inside the aggregation function, like this:

```
SELECT
      robotAds."Ad_ID"
    , count(CASE 
            WHEN robotSession."Session_start" BETWEEN '2020-11-25 00:00:00'
                    AND '2021-04-01 00:00:00'
                THEN 1
            END)                     AS range_ad_impression
    , count(robotScraper."adIDAdID") AS all_ad_impression
FROM robot__ads robotAds
LEFT JOIN robot__session__scraper__data robotScraper ON robotScraper."adIDAdID" = robotAds."Ad_ID"
LEFT JOIN robot__session_data robotSession ON robotSession."id" = robotScraper."sessionIDId"
GROUP BY robotAds."Ad_ID"
```

Note: the `count()` function ignores NULLs, above I have ommitted an explicit instruction to return NULL but some prefer to do this using `else` i.e.

```
,count(CASE 
        WHEN robotSession."Session_start" BETWEEN '2020-11-25 00:00:00'
                AND '2021-04-01 00:00:00'
            THEN 1 ELSE NULL
        END) AS range_count
```